# How to change toString() for primitive types' implicit conversions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

As an experiment, I did something like this:

```
Object.prototype.toString=function(){
  alert('works!');
}
'test'+{}; // alert is shown
```

However, this doesn't work for primitives:

```
Number.prototype.toString=function(){
  alert('works!');
}
'test'+123; // no alert
'test'+(new Number(123)); // no alert
(123).toString(); // yes alert
```

Is it possible for primitive implicit conversions to use a custom `toString` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, Javascript is calling `.valueOf()` first.

```
Number.prototype.valueOf = function(){ alert('works!'); }
```

This will alert because it's using the Number object:

```
'test'+(new Number(123))
```

This doesn't alert, I believe because `123` isn't getting autoboxed into a `Number`:

```
'test'+123
```

Javascript **does** have primitive types (aka an "unboxed" number, aka *doesn't* inherit from Object) but I don't believe you can modify those primitive prototypes. So **no**, you cannot overload pure primitive value functions.

Comment: _"I believe because 123 isn't getting autoboxed into a `Number`"_ I believe you are correct.